# Run S2I build as a remote job on kubernetes

Tags: docker, openshift, s2i

I have an image-build I want to run using S2I. I know I can run it locally using `s2i build ...`. If I wanted to run the same build remotely in K8s, I could create a job image containing the S2I CLI and call `s2i build` in that image, but this seems redundant. As I understand it, the build is a docker process running in the base image, so I was wondering if there is a way to avoid creating the job image and just have the build run remotely as a Kubernetes job. Sorry if this question is naive.

Comment: If you are using OpenShift, why not create a build configuration linked to a hosted Git repository, with a web hook trigger? Thus when push to the hosted Git repository, it can do an automatic build. Maybe read about source to image builds in OpenShift in free ebook at https://www.openshift.com/deploying-to-openshift/

Comment: In this case, we are programmatically building many images so having a git-repository (or even directory in a repo) per image is not feasible.